# jsf 2.0 working with javascript prevents ajax call

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm working on a JSF 2 project. Got some javascript/jQuery functions on client side, after calling for all these functions `<a4j:commandButton>` is not working. I get

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:441)
```

If I change `<a4j:commandButton>` to `<h:commandButton>`, then everything works fine, but I need the `a4j` because of `oncomplete` attribute.

How can I debug this issue? It looks like problem with javascript event, that prevents ajax call.

Comment: I think this is an IE7 / JBoss issue.  I found a little information here (http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4361)

Comment: Please edit the question to include a fullworthy SSCCE. There are too many possible factors for this to fail.

Comment: I'm not sure this question really fits for StackOverflow.  I have created to JIRA entries, one for Mojarra and one for RichFaces, because it's not clear where the issue lies. (http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2666) and (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12693) where I have provided more information.  @BalusC, should I add this kind of information to this quesiton, or should I just remove the bounty (if I can)?

Comment: provide your code to understand, this is not much enough.

Comment: @jubinPatel Thanks for the suggestion.  I added an edit, but it was rejected.  I'm going to try to create a war file and add it to the JIRA's.  Once this is complete, I'll take another shot at editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tracked down this problem to determine it is due to a `<button>` tag being in the html.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="example">
        <a4j:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <button>button</button>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My theory is the JavaScript that is submitting the AJAX is somehow confused by the `<button>` tag in IE7 causing an invalid post to the server.

Without seeing your HTML, I can't be certain this is your issue.

Check the following JIRA posts for more information.

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2666

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12693

Pavol Pitonak over at RichFaces discovered that if you add a `name` attribute to the `<button>` then the error will go away.